# Optional token at end of file

Tags: predicate, antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar to parse a file where blank lines indicate the end of a block.  I have grammar similar to this which almost works.

```
file : block+ EOF;
block : line+ NL;
line : stuff NL;

NL : '\r'? '\n';
```

This works except that the last block sometimes does not have an extra newline.  Is there a good way to make the NL at the end of block optional when I am at the end of the file?

In antlr3, I would have done

```
block : line+ (NL | (EOF) => /* empty */ )
```

However, antlr4 does not have syntactic predicates, so I can't do that.

```
block : line+ NL? ;
```

should work, but then a block in the middle of the file could avoid its final newline.  I don't think it will since a block can only be followed by a block.  That means a block without the trailing newline followed by a block looks like one single block, and the parser will greedily combine them.  However, it makes it less clear what the structure actually is.  I can certainly imagine more complicated source file formats where this causes a problem.

Is there a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
file : NL* block (NL+ block)* NL* EOF;
block : line (NL line)*;
line : stuff;

NL : '\r'? '\n';
```

Or simply append a line break at the end of your input.

Comment: That would work.  It's not as streamlined as what I originally had, but it is also more correct.